# Problems with ggplot2: draw a vertical line between x axis (from y=0) to the maximum point at each x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph the number of times a price appears in my database group by chain, represent the chain with different colours and draw a line that connect the x axis (y=0) to the maximum point at each price (x value) with the chain colour. If two different chains have the same price I want the lines to overlap. This is my data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lepk.png)

For example: price 39.5 appears two times for chain b, and one for chain a.

I want a graph with points and lines. Each point must be the number of times a price appears in each chain coloured according to chain. Up to this point I can graph it, I get this graph:

[Graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbOs2.png)

The problem arises when I try to connect points with x axis, I try geom_segment but it gives me a weird graph with diagonal lines when the same price appears in more than one chain, like this:

[Graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCdWI.png)

This is my code:

```
gP1 <- ggplot(fP1, aes(Price, N, color=Chain), group=Price) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=N, color=Chain, group=Price), yend=0)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I want to get a graph like this one:

[Graph3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYwl8.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with tthe output of `dput(fP1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(fP1, 20))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach with `geom_segment()` defining the proper values for x and y positions. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
fP1 <- data.frame(Price=c(39.5,39.5,39.9,39.9,40,42.5,42.8,45,46,47.9,50),
                 Chain=c('a','b','h','c','d','e','f','f','e','f','g'),
                 N=c(1,2,1,4,1,1,1,1,2,1,3))
#Plot
ggplot(fP1, aes(Price, N, color=Chain, group=Price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment( aes(x=Price, xend=Price, y=0, yend=N))+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

The previous sketch considers all the setting for `geom_segment()`. It can by simplified to this (Many thanks and all credit to **@RuiBarradas**):

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(fP1, aes(Price, N, color=Chain, group=Price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment( aes(xend=Price,yend=0))+
  theme_bw()
```

It will produce same output.

Comment: You can simplify `geom_segment`, only `xend=Price, yend=0` are needed. Upvote, btw.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I will update the post with credits to you! Obrigado!

Comment: Thanks so much @RuiBarradas and Duck. It was easy, but I can't figure it out by myself.